# Riddle downvote causes

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I'm just curious, why do people downvote riddles? Is it simply because they're too broad or because of something else?

I have tried searching on Puzzling Meta and the FAQ for an answer and was surprised to not find anything.

Comment: See also: [Recent influx of low effort riddles?](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4676/recent-influx-of-low-effort-riddles)

Comment: Do you have any specific examples of downvoted riddles you're unsure about? Talking about downvotes in the general case, while interesting, might be less helpful to you than a specific case.

Answer (score 7):

I downvote some riddles, and upvote others.  I guess it's somewhat subjective, but some riddles seem to have a lot of effort put into them: they employ wordplay or alternate meanings of a word, they scan well, the answer is not something extremely obscure, the answer is obvious once you hear it and clearly fits all clues in the riddle, etc.

Some riddles seem to have little effort put into them, and even when the solution is found/provided, it's unclear how certain clues fit the answer (or they could easily fit other answers).  Sometimes the answer is some character in a comic book that less than 1% of the population has ever heard of.  Those are the ones I generally downvote.

Comment: Ah; it's nice to see that I'm not the only person who believes that riddles should not require that you know obscure information.